# Unable to pass `pyarrow` table to `arrow::Table`

Tags: c++, pybind11, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I'm trying to pass a `pyarrow` table to `c++` via `pybind11`. In this example I'm simply trying to print the number of rows of a `pyarrow` table passed from `python`.

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <arrow/python/pyarrow.h>

// Convert pyarrow table to native C++ object and print its contents
void print_table(PyObject* py_table)
{
    // convert pyobject to table
    auto status = arrow::py::unwrap_table(py_table);
    if (!status.ok())
    {
        std::cout << "Error converting pyarrow table to arrow table" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table> table = status.ValueOrDie();
    std::cout << "Table has " << table->num_rows() << " rows" << std::endl;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(df_test, m)
{
    arrow::py::import_pyarrow();
    m.doc() = "Pyarrow Extensions";
    m.def("print_table", &print_table);
}
```

However I get the following error:

```
 error: member access into incomplete type 'std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table>::element_type' (aka 'arrow::Table')
    std::cout << "Table has " << table->num_rows() << " rows" << std::endl;
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Try `#include <arrow/table.h>`

Comment: Yup. That fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error tells you that the c++ class `arrow::Table` is missing its full definition. That is often the case if the class is only *declared* in some header but not *defined*.

To fix the error, you probably need to add an `#include` statement.
The definition might be in the header "arrow/table.h" as suggested in the comments, but I am not familiar with the Apache arrow framework so you may have to checkout the documentation.

Comment: Indeed, adding `#include <arrow/table.h>` fixed it. Thanks.